# c++ mode indentation

Tags: indentation, c++

If we have a class like the one below emacs is indenting the : (to the initialization list). To be able to match some other editor, is it possible in emacs to indent the : like below?

```
class Test
{
public:
   Test(int a, int b)
   :
      m_a{a}, m_b{b}
   {
   }
private:
   int m_a, m_b;
};
```

currently the indentation is like this:

```
class Test
{
public:
   Test(int a, int b)
      :
      m_a{a}, m_b{b}
   {
   }
private:
   int m_a, m_b;
};
```

Comment: could you also give example for how the default configuration is indenting

Comment: I believe Emacs uses the same styles for indenting C and C++ (not 100% sure though). Look what styles are listed in `c-style-alist` variable, and try them by setting `c-default-style`.